# Karnaugh Map and Mirroring

Tags: karnaugh-map

In widening Karnaugh map, what Mirroring means?

I can not understand the name of Mirroring, could you explain?

Answer (score 0):

Mirroring of a Karnaugh map means that the table is reflected across a line. For example if you had a K-Map that was in four variables B, C, D and E and then wanted to mirror it whilst adding variable A the result would look something like the following:

[image]

Not how the rows reflect across the red line. The same scheme can be used to make the map wider (adding more columns as opposed to adding more rows) as shown above.